# Exclude from a string everything after certain character

Tags: bash, grep

When running command to get php version `php -v` I get that long output which I want to reduce so the output is i.e.

```
PHP 7.3.27-9
```

instead of

```
PHP 7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
(built: Feb 23 2021 15:10:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

This would mean leaving everything after sign `-` or `+`.

Currently, I have this:
`php -v | grep -e '^PHP [5.*,7.*,8.*]$*'`

Which gives output:

`PHP 7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:10:08) ( NTS )`

I would like to leave out everything after `PHP 7.3.27`.

Comment: What have you tried to far?

Comment: Note that the string changes. On my old system I have `$ php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) 
Copyright....`. (i.e. there are no `-` or `+` signs)

Comment: @markp-fuso gave me a good answer: `php -v | awk -F'-' '/^PHP/{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `awk` ?

```
php -v | awk -F'-' '/^PHP/{print $1}'
```

Comment: this prints `$1` for all 5 lines; I'm assuming you want something like `awk -F'-' '$1 ~ "PHP"{print $1}' ` or `awk -F'-' '/^PHP/{print $1}' php.out` ? and for overkill ... `{print $1;exit}` to make sure you don't process any follow-on lines that may contain/start-with `PHP`

Comment: Ref to the solution of Jetchisel:
If I use this solution, the output is:
`PHP 5.6.40
Copyright (c) 1997
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6`

Comment: I want to mark @markp-fuso answer as the one that answered my question; this works perfectly for what I try to achieve: `php -v | awk -F'-' '/^PHP/{print $1}'`. the output is: `PHP 5.6.40`

Thank you all

Comment: @markp-fuso, Updated accordingly much oblige.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter expansion.

```
v=$(php -v)
echo "${v%%-*}"
```

`%` removes the pattern on the right hand side, doubling the percent sign makes it greedy, i.e. it removes the longest part possible (i.e. starting at the first dash from the left).

Answer (score 1):

Use `php`, it's there.

```
php -r 'print(PHP_VERSION);'
```